# Join of classifying spaces is contractible

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

> Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct prime, and consider the classifying spaces $X=BC_p$ and $Y=BC_q$, where $C_p$ is the cyclic group of order $p$. Prove that the join $X*Y$ is contractible.

I am not sure how to think topologically about the classifying space of a cyclic group. Also, is the correct way to think about the join is as a homotopy pushout?

Comment: Nitpick on language - *maps* are homotopic, while *spaces* are homotopy-equivalent.

Comment: Presume you mean $C_p$ and $C_q$ are cyclic groups of order $p$ and $q$ respectively? I think that is fairly obvious but it's better to define notation you introduce.  $X$ and $Y$ are known as Eilenberg-Mac Lane spaces, which means they have a very simple structure in terms of homotopy groups (but NOT homology); I don't know offhand how to describe homotopy groups of a join but these could be a couple of points for you to look at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Seifert-Van Kampen theorem implies that $\pi_1(BC_p\ast BC_q)$ is the pushout of $$C_p\leftarrow C_p\times C_q\rightarrow C_q,$$
which is trivial if $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes. I claim that $H_\ast(BC_p\ast BC_q)$ vanishes in positive degrees. Then Hurewicz implies that all homotopy groups of $BC_p\ast BC_q$ vanish.

For any two spaces $X$ and $Y$ there is a split short exact sequence $$0\to \tilde{H}_k(X\ast Y)\to \tilde{H}_{k-1}(X\times Y)\to \tilde{H}_{k-1}(X)\oplus \tilde{H}_{k-1}(Y)\to 0,$$
see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1103224/join-of-topological-spaces-mayer-vietoris?noredirect=1&lq=1). This is a straightforward application of the Mayer-Vietoris sequence and uses the fact that the projections $X\times Y\to X$ and $X\times Y\to Y$ have sections. It thus suffices to show that $\tilde{H}_k(BC_p\times BC_q)\to \tilde{H}_k(BC_p)\oplus \tilde{H}_k(BC_q)$ is injective. For any $n$ we have
$$H_k(BC_n) = \begin{cases} \mathbb{Z} &\text{if } k=0,\\
\mathbb{Z}/n &\text{if } k \text{ is odd},\\
0 &\text{otherwise},
\end{cases}$$
and since $$\mathrm{Tor}^1_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}/n;\mathbb{Z}/m)=0=\mathbb{Z}/n\otimes\mathbb{Z}/m$$
if $n$ and $m$ are coprime, the Künneth formula implies that
$$\tilde{H}_k(BC_p\times BC_q)\cong\mathbb{Z}/p\oplus \mathbb{Z}/q\cong\tilde{H}_k(BC_p)\oplus \tilde{H}_k(BC_q)$$
for odd $k$ and is zero otherwise. We see that
$$\tilde{H}_k(BC_p\times BC_q)\to \tilde{H}_k(BC_p)\oplus \tilde{H}_k(BC_q)$$
is a surjection between finite groups of the same cardinality, hence it must be also be injective.

Comment: This should also work for $C_n$ and $C_m$ with $n$ and $m$ coprime.

Comment: Small typo: one of the $\tilde{H}_{k-1}(X)$ should be $\tilde{H}_{k-1}(Y)$.

Comment: @user10354138 Fixed!